# Find last occurrence of a space in a string & replace with ':' in Spark dataframe

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have dates & time separated by a space in a string format in spark dataframe column like this -

```
DTC
11 AUGUST 2012 10:12
12 AUGUST 2012 10:12
13 AUGUST 2012 10:12
```

I want to replace last space in each date with ':' in the same column. Output should look like this

```
DTC
11 AUGUST 2012:10:12
12 AUGUST 2012:10:12
13 AUGUST 2012:10:12
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Match on

```
^(.*) (.*)$
```

and substitute with

```
\1:\2
```

Match:

- `^` - start of line anchor
- `(.*)`  - match and capture zero or more characters followed by a space, greedy
- `(.*)` - match and capture zero or more characters
- `$` - end of line anchor

Substitute:

- `\1` - the first capture
- `:` - a literal `:`
- `\2` - the second capture

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tmZpLa/1)

Comment: How to write it in spark regexp_replace method ?

Comment: @VikasGarud I'd expect something like [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html) ... `regexp_replace('column_name', r'^(.*) (.*)$', '\1:\2'))` or just `regexp_replace('column_name', r'^(.*) ', '\1:'))` to work. I don't have a spark instance to try it on myself unfortunately, but since you mentioned pyspark, I hope the python regexes will do the trick.

Comment: Somehow it's not working.

Comment: @VikasGarud Can you put an example of a working `regexp_replace` in the question? Just replace `'0'` with `'X'` or something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Date and timestamp tranformations are well catered for in python. Acquint yourself with the date and timestamp functions and will save you heaps.

coerce the string to timestamp using pyspark's to `to_timestamp` and the format using `date_format`

Data

```
 df=spark.createDataFrame([ ( 1 , '11 AUGUST 2012 10:12' ),
     ( 1  ,'12 AUGUST 2012 10:12')],
    ('id' ,'DTC'  ))
```

Code

```
df.withColumn('DTC',date_format(to_timestamp('DTC',"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"),"dd MMMM yyyy:HH:mm")).show()
```

outcome

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                 DTC|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|11 August 2012:10:12|
|  1|12 August 2012:10:12|
```

Comment: I am already familiar with spark timestamp functions but they can't be used as dates can be even partial in data like this  AUGUST 2012 10:12

spark timestamp function will make it null & I will loose the data. Hence it has to be handled as a string using regex.

Comment: Just thought I would mention. For me, I would look at the dates and format them. Anyway, will leave my answer here just in case someone interested in approaching a similar problem the same way can use it. Good on you!